# How to insert greek symbols properly in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, graphing

I want to use greek letters in different labels in gnuplot. But in 'wxt' terminal the letters are not very clear, I mean I got the greek letter but not in the font I wanted. In return I got Some squeezed version of it. How to get proper greek letters such as we see in Word or LaTeX ?

I know how to get symbols. That is not my problem.
`set xlabel "{/Symbol a}"`
I have tried changing fonts, encoding, terminals. But no result. I don't want postscript mode solution, even though, I didn't get any result in that also.

Comment: Have you tried `set term wxt font "Arial"`?

Comment: Do you mean that you are trying to get an alpha by saying `{/Symbol a}`?  Don't do that - it is exactly the PostScript-only solution you don't want.  Simply provide the α character directly and it will look like whatever the current font provides.  You give no information about your environment or O/S.  Possibly you should do `set encoding utf8` first, although that is the default on most modern systems.  If you need more help please show the actual sequence of commands you are using.

Comment: Many Thanks. I got the result. But there's not every symbol available. What should we do for those symbols ?

Answer (score 0):

What is the font you wanted? Have you installed that font? What symbols are missing? Please show your script and the resulting graph.

**Script:**

```
### greek letters in different fonts
reset session

grAlphabet = "ΑαΒβΓγΔδΕεΖζΗηΘθΙιΚκΛλΜμΝνΞξΟοΠπΡρΣσ/ςΤτΥυΦφΧχΨψΩω"

set label 1 at graph 0.01, graph 0.9 "Default:\n".grAlphabet         font ",14"
set label 2 at graph 0.01, graph 0.7 "Arial:\n".grAlphabet           font "Arial,14"
set label 3 at graph 0.01, graph 0.5 "Times New Roman:\n".grAlphabet font "Times New Roman,14"
set label 4 at graph 0.01, graph 0.3 "Courier New:\n".grAlphabet     font "Courier New,14"

plot x lt nodraw notitle
### end of script
```

**Result:** (wxt-terminal, gnuplot 5.2.8, Win10)

[image]

Comment: Many Thanks. But My ```ALT``` keys are giving separate reults. Such as ALT+936 gives me ¿ instead of \Psi , and ALT+968 gives me ╚ instead of \psi. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

**Script with wxt enhanced option for Greek letters:**

```
### greek letters in different fonts

reset session

set terminal wxt enhanced

grAlphabet = "ΑαΒβΓγΔδΕεΖζΗηΘθΙιΚκΛλΜμΝνΞξΟοΠπΡρΣσ/ςΤτΥυΦφΧχΨψΩω"

set label 1 at graph 0.01, graph 0.9 "Default:\n".grAlphabet         font ",14"
set label 2 at graph 0.01, graph 0.7 "Arial:\n".grAlphabet           font "Arial,14"
set label 3 at graph 0.01, graph 0.5 "Times New Roman:\n".grAlphabet font "Times New Roman,14"
set label 4 at graph 0.01, graph 0.3 "Courier New:\n".grAlphabet     font "Courier New,14"

plot x lt nodraw notitle

pause mouse close

### end of script
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).